# ¿Por qué no me compila XML en un proyecto JAVA?

Tags: java, xml, netbeans

Tengo un proyecto en `Netbeans` basado en `JAVA`, en este proyecto dispongo de un fichero `XML` donde guardo el valor de la `MAC` del equipo donde se ejecuta, y después muestro otro valor que me genera a partir de esa `MAC`. Cuando corro el documento en `Netbeans` funciona sin problema, pero cuando creo el `.jar` y ejecuto este `.jar` funciona pero no me recoge el dato del `XML` generado a partir de la `MAC` que se recogía.
La escritura y lectura es mediante `DOM`.

¿Alguna solución o alternativa?

Gracias

Comment: Ten en cuenta que compilar y ejecutar son dos procesos diferentes.

Comment: Gracias @LuiggiMendoza pero no comprendo por que me ejecuta bien y si después ejecuto lo que he compilado no me muestra los mismos resultados.

Comment: Por favor explica el problema en detalle. Edita la pregunta y agrega input y output esperados y qué sucede cuando lo ejecutas fuera del IDE.

Comment: Los XML no se compilan, sólo se leen, es un simple archivo del cual obtienes o escribes datos, agrega el código con el cual estás intentando leer el XML es posible que tengas algún error ahí

Comment: Ya la edite @LuiggiMendoza

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y provee más detalles. Con esa información no se puede entender el problema. Esto es: agrega código, indica la configuración que usas para leer el archivo xml, muestra dónde se encuentra el xml cuando ejecutas la aplicación desde el IDE y fuera de él, etc. Todos los detalles que sean relevantes para entender el problema.

Comment: Ejecuta el jar desde la terminal y muestra la salida que arroja. Te sugeriría también usar JAXB, así puedes leer y escribir el XML como una clase(s) Java.

Comment: Hablas de "correr el documento" y de "compilar un XML". Es imposible entender qué quieres decir con eso. Los documentos no se corren y los XML no se compilan.

Answer (score 0):

Debes tener en cuenta el árbol de directorios cuando se compila y ejecuta la clase, es decir, dentro del IDE puedes llegar al directorio donde se encuentra el XML, pero en el .jar no. Puedes probar imprimiendo el `path` donde se ejecuta la clase y comparas la salida cuando ejecutas en el IDE y cuando ejecutas con el .jar

Answer (score 0):

Comprueba que el path del xml esta interno en el proyecto. Además de hacer las llamadas al xml de forma interna y no llamar al path de forma externa.

Si el .jar lo estas llamando dentro de otro proyecto cuida si tienes declaradas las librerías que usas para manejar el xml (si usas librerías externas cómo Apache Commons,  etc)